# How to separate the data plot for spin up and spin down band structure into 2 different graphs, in Pymatgen?

Tags: vasp, band-structure, visualization-software, pymatgen

I am a beginner user of the Pymatgen package. In order to process the data from VASP DFT calculation software, I use Pymatgen to visualize the output band structure. When I do spin polarised band calculation, I cannot separate the band structure of spin up and spin down into 2 different subplots or graphs. Can anyone tell me how can I deal with this? Because it looks messy when the package automatically plot it into the same graph.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here I provide an example with my own python scripts to realize your purpose rather than using Pymatgen (You can save data firstly with Pymatgen and plot with python). I assume that you can perform correctly the band and dos calculations with the VASP code. The example I pick up is the monolayer FM NiBr$_2$ and the final result is the following:

[image]

- Example GitHub link: https://github.com/Kohn-X/VASP_two_spins

Comment: Thank you for your support. Your code work very well. May I ask one more question. Is it possible to also include the Projection plot in each plot ? I want to do the projection of electron from different type of atom. Ive already include the LORBIT tag in my INCAR file.

Comment: Of course, you can. You can project to atom/orbital.